# webkit rtl absolute position bug?

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, right-to-left

html:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#outer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    direction: rtl;
    background-color: blue;
}
#inner {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

In Chrome, the yellow box is outside of the blue box.

In other browers(firefox, IE), the yellow box is inside the blue box.

Is it a bug of webkit, and why?

a test case on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/QF9tT/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should simply remove `display: inline-block` from `#inner`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/QF9tT/1/

`position: absolute` will force a computed `display` value of `block`, so `display: inline-block` should not be doing anything whatsoever:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo

> Otherwise, if 'position' has the value
>   'absolute' or 'fixed', the box is
>   absolutely positioned, .., and display
>   is set according to the table below.
>
> [inline-block = block]

But, it appears in this case that this behaviour is buggy in Chrome.

You should consider filing a report here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Then again, the issue is easy to fix: don't specify a nonsensical `display` value on an absolutely positioned element.